# How to have Rails include the application.js instead of individual files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 7 app where I have JS files in /app/javascript/..., including application.js  The application.js file just looks like:

```
import "./application/first"
import "./application/second"
etc
```

I then use esbuild and `npm run watch` (or `npm run build`) to compile the JS into one file, outputting it to /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

This all works locally, but when I go to deploy the website in production, it has the application.js file that looks like this:

```
import "./application/first"
import "./application/second"
etc
```

That doesn't work at all.

This is being included with a normal JS include tag `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", media: :all, type: :module, defer: true %>`

It is like the compiled file is being overwritten by some part of the production deployment? How can I have it use the compiled file that I built?

Comment: Will need info on how you deploy/prepare for production

Comment: Rails 7 now has importmap support to aid in replacing npm if that is your goal https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails